# NextJs & Mongoose putting a jwt in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, jwt

I tryed myself on a little NextJS App with Mongoose and JWT (json web token).
Everything works and I can put user into my database and other stuff. Just when I create a JWT I can't put it into my database. Here is my code, grateful for every help :D

First my schema for mongoose:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add a title'],
        unique: true,
        maxlength: [15, 'Username cannot be more than 15 characters']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: [100, 'Password cannot be more than 100 characters'] 
    },
    jwt: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: [1000, 'JWT cannot be more than 200 characters'] 
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I don't know if type: String for jwt is correct, but JSON looks weird too and doesn't work.

Now my backend API Code:

```
import dbConnect from '../../../utils/dbConnect';
import User from '../../../models/User';
import sjcl from 'sjcl';
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const hashword = "censored"

dbConnect();

export default async (req, res) => {
    
    var passwordtohash = req.body.password + hashword
    const BitArrayHash = sjcl.hash.sha256.hash(passwordtohash);
    const passwordhashed = sjcl.codec.hex.fromBits(BitArrayHash)
    var bodywithhash = req.body
    bodywithhash.password = passwordhashed
    const { method } = req;
    
    switch(method) {
        case 'POST':
            try {
                const user = await User.find({"username": bodywithhash.username, "password": bodywithhash.password});
                if (user.length > 0) {
                    createJWT(user);
                    res.status(200).json({ success: true }) 
                } else (res.status(200).json({ success: false}))           
            } catch (error) {
                res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            }
            break;
        default:
            res.status(400).json({ success: false });
    }

}

async function createJWT(user) {
    jwt.sign({
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60),
        data: 'foobar'
    }, 'secret')
    const iduser = { "_id" : user[0]._id.toString()}
    const updateuser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(iduser, jwt);
}
```

All my users in the database have a default value for JWT called "default"

Comment: [`jwt.sign()`](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback) returns the token as a string, so you should do `const token = jwt.sign(...)` to retrieve it.

Comment: @juliomalves thx I will try it out and give u a feedback soon